# Refactoring PHP function Code for Better Readability

Tags: php

I have this Class function fr update session id:

```
/**
 * update session id in database
 *
 * @access public
 * @static static method
 * @param  string $userId
 * @param  string $sessionId
 */
public static function updateSessionId($userId, $sessionId = null)
{
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET session_id = :session_id WHERE user_id = :user_id";

    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':session_id' => $sessionId, ":user_id" => $userId));
}
```

Now I need to update another database table with name customers. I have two option:

add new Arguments `check` to this function like this :

```
public static function updateSessionId($userId,$check, $sessionId = null)

    if($check == 'users'){
     $sql = "UPDATE users SET session_id = :session_id WHERE user_id = :user_id";

..................

    } else {

     $sql = "UPDATE customers SET session_id = :session_id WHERE customer_id = :user_id";
........................
        }
```

Or Create/add new function for customers like this:

```
public static function updateCustomerSessionId($userId, $sessionId = null)
{.......}
```

What's Best Way for performance code?!

Comment: Wont affect performance, and readability is in the eye of the coder. So this will gain highly opinionated answers.

Comment: @IncredibleHat: performance.

Comment: You had performance/readability ... so my comment stands ... editing your question won't hide that ;) If you are that concerned about a performance difference of 'hunting for a method vs going through an if block' ... then you would have to be doing millions of actions per request, and if performance becomes an issue between the two, then you shouldn't be using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do

```
protected static $allowedTables = array('users', 'customers');

public static function updateSessionId($table, $userId, $sessionId = null)
{
    if (in_array($table, MySessionHandler::$allowedTables)) {

        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
        $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET session_id = :session_id WHERE user_id = :user_id";

        $query = $database->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':session_id' => $sessionId, ":user_id" => $userId));
    }
}
```

The main benefit i see here is that you can easily add or remove a table name.